# How is X/Y distributed when X and Y are uniformly distributed on [0,1]?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$,$Y$ be uniformly distributed continuous random variables on [0,1]. How is the random variable $X/Y$ distributed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uniform_ratio_distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1.** Let $A_k$ be the area of the portion of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ for which $y\leq k x$.

If $k\in[0,1]$, $A_k$ is the area of a right triangle with its perpendicular sides having lengths $1$ and $k$. If $k\geq 1$, $A_k$ is the area of the square minus the area of a right triangle with its perpendicular sides having length $1$ and $\frac{1}{k}$.

**Step 2.** Let $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$. $Z$ is obviously distributed over $\mathbb{R}^+$, and for any $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

$$ \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\leq k\right] = A_k = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{k}{2}&\text{if}& 0< k\leq 1\\ 1-\frac{1}{2k}&\text{if}& k\geq 1.\end{array}\right.$$

**Step 3.** By differentiating the previously computed CDF, we have that the probability density function of $Z$, say $f_Z(t)$, is distributed over $\mathbb{R}^+$, equals $\frac{1}{2}$ over $(0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{2t^2}$ over $[1,+\infty)$.